# "df" command making network requests?

Tags: macos, network, command-line

I was watching Little Snitch for another process, and noticed `df` was making requests to various servers. I thought `df` was only for checking free disk space locally, but it appears to be doing more than just that.

It calls out to a number of servers (current count is 38 different servers) and sends a few bytes each time. Subset of servers include:

- `talk.google.com`
- `safebrowsing-cache.google.com`
- `jsfiddle.net`
- `cdn2.sbnation.com`
- `urs.microsoft.com.nsatc.net`
- `api.facebook.com`

It seems like some kind of tracker, and it certainly doesn't seem like the behavior I'd expect from df. It's located in `/bin/df`, and run by `root`.

Any ideas? Normal behavior and I'm just paranoid?

I've tried blocking it with Little Snitch rules, but it seems to ignore them.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Which options did you use for `df`? And are you sure it's the real `df`? Try running `/bin/df` to be sure

Comment: /bin/df runs as normal, as far as I can tell. I don't use it at all in my day-to-day work, so it was odd to see it listed in the Little Snitch "Network Monitor".

Comment: And like I said, it "calls out" to these servers once every few seconds. But it's not actively running when I grep through "ps -ax". So something else is calling "/bin/df" and it's sending data from it. That's all I can tell so far. Little Snitch claims that the app is run by root, and is located at "/bin/df".

Comment: As a precaution, and while I'm figuring this out, I renamed "/bin/df" to "/bin/not_df" and restarted my machine. So far it has not come back in the Network Monitor. I will keep investigating as I have time.

Comment: If something is calling df, then probably a list of running programs is relevant. Also, it is prob a good idea to reboot and see if it runs before you launch any programs.

Comment: Do have any custom daemons or third-party apps that run in the background? Or any browser plugins or extensions?

Comment: Have you mounted any network storage in some way?

Comment: I looked through the list of running programs at the time I first noticed the issue, and nothing seemed out of place at the time. I have since rebooted, and like I said, the issue seems to have gone away for now (and possibly forever).

Comment: No custom daemons of my own, third-party apps running in the background are always possible, but nothing I could think of that would be doing what it was doing. No browser plugins/extensions--I keep it pretty clean in Chrome.

Comment: No mounted network storage. Unless TimeMachine, CrashPlan, etc, were doing something I wasn't aware of. Otherwise I do not use network stores on my local network.

Comment: @Carl can you double check output of `mount` command?

Comment: Loses all formatting, but it doesn't seem out of ordinary, but I don't check it very often: 

/dev/disk1 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
|
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
|
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
|
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
|
localhost:/YccRhVAyiG6eOtZm9827Hg on /Volumes/MobileBackups (mtmfs, nosuid, read-only, nobrowse)

Comment: What version of mac osx are you on? md5 /bin/df and match it against someone else's to see if it's legit.  I'm on 10.9.4 and get 1657374dc01d5d2cd0da943b37175955.

Comment: Thanks, pabo. Since I first asked the question, I've upgraded to OSX Mavericks 10.9.4, and my md5 hash matches yours. I haven't seen the network usage come back.